# Are there possible troubles to use default copy constructor in clone idiom?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have :

```
class myClass : public baseClass
{
public:

myClass(const unsigned short int    dim_alphabet ,const string *alf ,const map<vector<string>, int> &samples );
myClass(const approximateOracle& apOracle); //copy constructor
virtual ~myClass();
virtual myClass* clone() const;
virtual bool    myMethod(vector<SYMBOL> str);
virtual bool    myMethod2(dfa* dfahp , vector<SYMBOL>* witness_results=NULL);




private:

void encode_data(vector< pair<vector<double> , labelType> > &mapped_samples , const map<vector<string>, int> &samples);
int length_longer_sentence;
vector<double> mean;
vector<double> standard_deviation; //data structure for save the standard_deviation of features
```

where implementation of clone() is:

```
myClass* myClass::clone() const
{
return(new myClass(*this)); //this code cause the call of copy constructor
}
```

I'm using the clone idiom.
I would delete the explicit definition of the copy constructor. I haven't pointers that require deep copy. Thus, with the default copy constructor provided from compiler (if I delete the mine) the automatic shallow copy of members of myClass should be ok.

But I have some doubt because of the presence of the clone idiom. Is there any contraindication about delete the explicit copy constructor?

Comment: Using the default copy-constructor is one of the bases of [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Comment: You can't delete the copy constructor because you're using it in `clone`, but you might still make it private.

Comment: @aschepler -- by "delete" here, the text means "remove the definition", not mark it `deleted`.

Comment: @aschepler But if I delete the copy constructor there is the default copy constructor and is called the latter in clone() or not? Could you explain to me that utility has made it private?

Comment: Ah, yes, you can omit defining the copy constructor and use the default (which will be public).  But I meant you can't write `myClass(const myClass&) = delete;`, which is also called "deleting the copy constructor".

Comment: Use a unique_ptr and make_unique instead of a raw pointer and new in your clone function.

Comment: @manni66 This advice is for efficiency rasons is it true? But both the versions (the yours and mine) wotk

Comment: Not efficiency, but safety.so no `delete` required.

Comment: @Umbert it is to prevent memory leaks. It is to clearly state who owns a resource.